# Conflict of `scrartcl` and `subfig`?

Tags: subfloats

In a document I write, I use the documentclass `scrartcl` and the packages and `subfig`.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
   \centering
   \caption{Table}
   \subfloat[a]{
      \fbox{aaaa}
   }
   \\
   \subfloat[b]{
      \fbox{bbbb}
   }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

When compiled, I get the captions of the subfloats of `table` under the tabulars, but it should be above.

Using `article` as the documentclass removes this issue.
Can somebody explain this? How can I use `scrartcl` and get the captions of the subfloats positioned correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare that your captions are above:

```
\documentclass[captions=tableabove]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
   \centering
   \caption{Table}
   \subfloat[a]{
      \fbox{aaaa}
   }
   \\
   \subfloat[b]{
      \fbox{bbbb}
   }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I feel a little dumb now. Can you explain why this option does not affect the normal `\caption` command? If this would have been typeset under the table, I would probably have looked for an option like `captions=tableabove`.

Comment: It does affect the normal caption too: It changes the spacing. But beside this is depends on the packages if and what they do something with the setting.